# Python for loop in HTML snippet

Tags: python, html, loops, generator

Does anybody have an idea how to rewrite this code snippet into more clean code?
[image]

I tried to use a for loop but got this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) provides information to help you succeed. **The question does not include code. That increases the chance it will be downvoted or closed with no answer..** Make it easy for someone to help. They should not have to view pictures and type in the code.

Comment: Is `rows_amount` the same as `len(row)`? Then you should use `for col in row:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the rows_amount and add it like this.

```
table_html+='<tr>'
for row in schedule:
    for i in range(rows_amount):
        table_html+='<td>'+str(row[i])+'</td' #adding it to string
```